# Правильно ли расставлены кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

Автор ведет диалог с читателем, например, задает риторические вопросы:  “et pourquoi pas, un jour, la visiter ?”; “de l'eau peut-être, la vie sans doute ?”. Кроме того, присутствует ирония: “„seulement“ 4 années-lumière de nous”; “40 000 milliards de kilomètres „seulement“”...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автор ведёт диалог с читателем, например, задает риторические вопросы: «et pourquoi pas, un jour, la visiter?”, «de l'eau peut-être, la vie sans doute?». Кроме того, присутствует ирония: «„seulement“ 4 années-lumière de nous», «40 000 milliards de kilomètres „seulement“».

1. Цитируя в текст на русском, не следует переходить на другую, не традиционную для нас пунктуацию (имею ввиду кавычки в латинице).
2. Пробелы перед знаками вопроса (и другими знаками также) не нужно ставить.
3. При перечислении обычно пользуются запятыми. ТЧК/ЗПТ загромождают текст.

Comment: Пробелы перед знаками не нужно ставить, даже если так принято во французском? Не должен ли текст в кавычках оставаться неприкосновенным?

Comment: Не о тексте речь и не о пунктуации даже, а о привычной форме знака и его положении на строке. Как говорится: можно добавить, но не смешивать.